# Cannot start new activity from main activity's onCreate()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start a new activity `DirectorySelectionActivity` if the app is being launched for the first time immediately from the main activity but my main activity's `onCreate()` function is not starting the new activity as I expect. Instead, my main activity finishes it's `onCreate()` function and only after it's done with the `oncreate()` function does it move on to my `DirectorySelectionActivity`. How can I move to a new activity in the middle of my main activity's onCreate() function before finishing onCreate()? This is what I have:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {        
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);


        // If this is the first time user has run this app
         if(true){ // for testing
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
            /* I've also tried:
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
            */
            startActivity(intent);
            // Also tried:
            //this.startActivity(intent);

        }


        // This happens before my DirectorySelectionActivity activity gets started

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

DirectorySelectionActivity.java

```
public class DirectorySelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);



        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SelectUnwantedDirsFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: return after startActivity

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with an else statment

```
 // If this is the first time user has run this app
         if(true){ // for testing
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
            /* I've also tried:
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
            */
            startActivity(intent);
            // Also tried:
            //this.startActivity(intent);

        }else{



        // This happens before my DirectorySelectionActivity activity gets started

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

if you dont use an else, it will execute your first code and then continue untill it finishes executing all inside onCreate()

also it will inflate your fragment first because  your

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
```

you can try executing your code before `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if(true){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);` from your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` then it will not show up.  
But what if at some point you want it to show up?  
I suggest to use a Boolean flag like

```
if (flag) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you introduce a new class which extends Application class? So if it fine to start `DirectorySelectionActivity` before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);` 
I would put below code in that class.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
        /* I've also tried:
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
        */
        startActivity(intent);
        // Also tried:
        //this.startActivity(intent);
```

As per the docs, The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created. Also, do not forget to update your manifest file. 
Please take a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application

Answer (score -1):

Call finish() right after startActivity(intent):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectorySelectionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```